# Enable internationalization in keycloak admin console 19.0.2

Tags: keycloak

I've recently switched from keycloak 18.0.2 to 19.0.2 version.

In the old version I may enable internationalization in 'theme' tab.
In the new version this toggle is disappeared.

Where I can find it?

Answer (score 2):

On the new UI you need to go to Realm Settings > Localization as you can seen in the image below:

[image]